# Create Playlist

Tags: javascript, spotify

I'm trying to build a custom playlist. Having an array with track paths.

This is my try code.

```
var c = new models.BridgeCollection(models.Track,"CustomList");     
c.load('type','uri').done(function(){
    for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
        var artist = data[i];
        var s = models.Track.fromURI(artist.song); // this is track path
        s.load('name').done(function(){
            var d = c.add(s);
        });
    }
});
```

After this I'm trying to looks so the data is there with Snapshot like this with no success.

```
c.snapshot().done(function(snapshot) {
    var len = Math.min(snapshot.length, 50);
    for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        var d = snapshot.get(i);
    }
});
```

After a lot of looking in the editor I found that the response when adding the track looks like this. The error message "unknown request: undefined_append".
[image]

Answer (score 2):

Now I finally got it to work. Must say the new API is a little weird!

This loops an array with objects {song:'spotify:track:xxxxxx'}. Add them to a temp playlist, and when all is done create a list view and add to the html.

```
require(['$api/models','$api/models#Playlist','$views/list'], function(models,playlists,lists) {

    var listClass = lists.List;
    var sList = data;
    var p = models.Playlist.createTemporary("CustomList");
    p.done(function(pList){
        pList.load('tracks').done(function(loadedPlaylist){
            for (var i = 0; i < sList.length; i++) {
                var artist = sList[i];
                var track = models.Track.fromURI(artist.song); // this is track path
                track.load('name','uri').done(function(loadedTrack){
                    loadedPlaylist.tracks.add(loadedTrack);
                });
            }

            var listObj = listClass.forPlaylist(loadedPlaylist,{header:'fixed',type:'tracks',fetch:'scroll',fields:['artist'], height:'fixed', unplayable:'disabled'});
            document.getElementById('playlistHolder').appendChild(listObj.node);
            listObj.init();

        });
    });


});
```